# I am not able to view Last Login on Facebook in Active Session option

Tags: facebook, account-management, security, location, ip-addresses

My Facebook ID has been hacked. I tried searching the location by visiting Active Session option but it shows only the current active session IP, which is used by me.
All last 3 login are removed. Is there any other way to find out who logged in last and from where it was logged.